# Can't get value from input text on keyup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, keyup

I'm trying to get the value of an `<input type=text>` with the method keyup from jQuery but whenever i log it it logs undefined.

Here is my code:

```
$.each(editables,function(i){
    current  = $(editables[i]);
    var value;              
    current.on('keyup', function(){
        value = $(this).val();
        console.log( value );
    });
    current.html( value );
});
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have a table wich displays all the information of a database, and i have a button to edit the information, what i do is i convert all of the `<td class="editable">` to an `<input type="text">` and i'm trying to get the value from them after i click the button again, i will send the info via `$.post()` but i can't get the value from these inputs

**EDIT 2**
Here is the full code of the handler hope it helps, thanks to all that have contributed
$('.edit').on('click',function(e){

```
    $this = $(this);
    editables = $this.parents('tr').find('td.editable');

    if($this.text() == "Save"){
        row  = $this.parents('tr');
        table = row.data('table');
        id = row.data('id');
        field = row.data('field');
        /*
        $.each(editables,function(i){
            current  = $(editables[i]);
            var value;              
            current.on('keyup', function(){
                value = $(this).val();
                console.log( value );
            });
            console.log( current );
            current.html( value );
        });
        */
        editables.each(function(i){
            var current = $(this);
                value;
            current.on('keyup',function(){
                value = $(this).val();
                console.log(value);
            })
        });

        $this.val('Edit');  

    } else {            

        $.each(editables,function(i){
            current  = $(editables[i]);
            currentValue = current.text();

            current.html("<input type='text' value='"+currentValue+"'></input>");
        });     

        $this.val('Save');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPDATE**
there was something else wrong in my code outside of the one i shared here that messed up the funcionality.

Thanks to everyone who helped

Comment: What is `editables` in your code?

Comment: Please post a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)...

Comment: `editables` it's an array with all the elements of the class editable, wich are `<td>`

Comment: Are you sure `editables` isn't a jQuery object?

Comment: the `keyup` listener is binding to the `<td>` not the `<input>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`editables` is still the `<td>` tag based on your updated code, not the input that is now inside. Use the `.find` to target the new input tags instead.

```
   editables.find('input').each(function(i){
        var current = $(this);
            value;
        current.on('keyup',function(){
            value = $(this).val();
            console.log(value);
        })
    });
```

(Answer to updated question above)

---

(Answer to original question below)

First, you need to move your `.html()` statement inside the `.on('keyup'`. Otherwise it will run only once and before `keyup` has occurred. Essentially what you are doing is: 
1. initialize `value`. 2. set `current.html` to the initialized variable with no value (`undefined`). 3. Listen for `keyup`. 4. On `keyup` change value of the variable and do nothing.

When `.html()` is inside the `.on` it will run only after `keyup` and on each `keyup`. Which guarantees `value` will be more than initialized before its used.

```
$.each(editables,function(i){
    current  = $(editables[i]);
    var value; 
    var currentTextField = $('#theInput'); //should be relational to the editable, not a straight selection query as shown here             
    currentTextField.on('keyup', function(){
        value = currentTextField.val();
        console.log( value );
        current.html( value );
    });

});
```

assuming editables are regions in which you wish to display the outcome of the text field. The `current` editable is not the text field itself and will not respond to `keyup` or `.val()`

**OR**

If editables are actually the text fields themselves, then they have no interior and you cannot use `.html()` on them. Nor should you want to. So assuming you DO with to output the result on the page somewhere.

```
$.each(editables,function(i){
    current  = $(editables[i]);
    var value; 
    var currentTextField = $('#outPutLocation'); //should be relational to the editable, not a straight selection query as shown here             
    current.on('keyup', function(){
        value = current.val();
        console.log( value );
        currentTextField.html( value );
    });     
});
```